# Mapeamento de imagem

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web

Fui mapear uma imagem com a tag map e não esta dando certo. o Código está certo?

```
<div class="botao_comprar">
  <?
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/textos/como_funciona/5/' or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/leilao/Curso-Profissionalizante-de-Telemarketing-EAD-leilao-de-centavos/459/'):
      echo '<img src="../../../img/site/botaolances.jpg"  usemap="#mapa-botao"/>';
    else:
      echo '<img src="../img/site/botaolances.jpg" usemap="#mapa-botao"/>';
    endif;           
  ?>
  <map name="mapa-botao">
    <area shape = “rect” coords = “8, 158, 213, 183” href=”jdlsites.com” target="_blank"/>
  </map>
```

Comment: Atenção as aspas que não são aspas corretas, estas `“` e que deveriam ser `"`. Essas regra geral são colocadas por editores que não de desenvolvimento, tipo Word e afins